# Embedding youtube videos problem

Tags: video, youtube

I have some site where I am embedding a couple of youtube videos in the middle. Site also has a gallery on the same page with picture thumbnails. I have a JS that on click displays bigger picture in an iFrame. My problem is that my embedded youtube videos are on top of everything and covering parts of displayed picture. Is there any way of overriding this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add the *wmode* parameter/attribute with the value "*opaque*" to the object and embed elements, for example:

```
<object width='425' height='344'> 
    <param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/hQVTIJBZook&hl=en&fs=1'> 
    <param name='type' value='application/x-shockwave-flash'> 
    <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'> 
    <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'> 
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <embed width='425' height='344'
            src='http://www.youtube.com/v/hQVTIJBZook&hl=en&fs=1'
            type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
            allowfullscreen='true'
            allowscriptaccess='always'
            wmode="opaque">
    </embed> 
</object>
```